# Better way to iterate over array and append to html using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am wondering if there is a shorter/better way to iterate through an array that contains {key:[array],key2:[array]}

```
var ray = {'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
'B': ['m', 'n', 'b', 'v', 'c', 'x', 'z'],
'C': ['o', 'i', 'd', 'f', 'j', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd']
}
```

At the moment I have

```
    function(data) {
        var ray = data.result;
        $.each(ray, function() {
          if(this == ray.A){
            $.each(this, function(i, v) {
              $("#list1").append('<span class="tag">' + v + "</span>");
            });
          }
          if(this == ray.B){
            $.each(this, function(i, v) {
              $("#list2").append('<span class="tag2">' + v + "</span>");
            });
          }

        });
    }
```

etc..

is there a better way to do this without the excessive duplication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your data type, you may do as follows in general...

```
Object.keys(ray).forEach(k => ray[k].forEach(e => doSomethingWith(k,e)))
```

Comment: will give this a try! didn't know javascript has this! is it widely browser supported ?

Comment: @Fanna1119 The only thing that's new is the arrow functions which are a part of the ES6 specs. Arrows are fine with almost all browsers for a long time now. (Latest to support was Safari 10+ in MAC) It's trivial to convert the arrows to the classical function definitions though. For example `x => x` is `function(x){ return x;}`

Comment: then it's perfect! i will just change the few bits! thank you. as i noticed IE11 does not support it although all others do. combining this with @jafarbtech answer got me to the right path. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#list"+j).append` with looping as the `list` has same name.

```js
var ray = {'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
'B': ['m', 'n', 'b', 'v', 'c', 'x', 'z'],
'C': ['o', 'i', 'd', 'f', 'j', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd']
}
    function arr() {
        var j=0;
        $.each(ray, function() {
            j++;
            $.each(this, function(i, v) {
              $("#list"+j).append('<span class="tag">' + v + "</span>");
            });
        });
    }
    
    arr();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list1">
</div>
<div id="list2">
</div>
<div id="list3">
</div>
```